# Mapboxgl:Always show layer icon while zoom in and out after certain zoom level

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to disable disappearing MapboxGl.Layer icon while zoom in out.Is there any metadata or property configuration to show layer all icon at onces.

for example after `minzoom:7.4` as below given in layer instance i want to show all geojson data.

```
{
  "id": "Car",
  "type": "symbol",
  "source": {
    "type": "geojson",
    "data": {
      "type": "FeatureCollection",
      "features": [
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "properties": {
            "icon": "Car"
          },
          "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
              -117.42187500000001,
              57.51582286553883
            ]
          }
        },
      ...
      ...
      ]
    }
  },
  "layout": {
    "icon-image": "{icon}",
    "icon-size": 0.04,
    "visibility": "visible"
  },
  "minzoom": 7.4,
  "metadata": {
    "imageurl": "dist/images/Mapboxgl/Entities/Car.png",
    "center": [
      -119.09913365922579,
      56.054006240841346
    ],
    "zoom": [
      12
    ]
  }
}
```

How to display all data together at zoom level 7.4?

**Added example:**
[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-mapboxgl-example-7z9hz)
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CPRam/opabsz50/10/)
click on **addLayer** button.

**Actual result**:Only displying layer 3 icons.

**Expected result**:Want to show all Layer icon show.

please any help.

Thanks.

Comment: You should include all your mapbox-gl code. I don't quite understand what you're asking - by default, mapbox will display symbol layers at all zoom levels.

Comment: @steveBennett i want to display all layer icon onces reach zoom in level 7.4.....but currently while doing zoom in and out some of icon displaying and some of disappearing..so i want to update disappearance behavior of icon.mean always it should show.whether zoom in or out should not effect.And onces zoom out more than 7.4 disappear all.

Comment: adding 'icon-allow-overlap': true, in your layers layout section will do it.

Answer (score 1):

When adding the layer in the SymbolLayer make sure to include the following options:

```
layout: { 'icon-allow-overlap': true, }
```

If you are using text as part of the SymbolLayer make sure to also include:

```
layout: { 'icon-allow-overlap': true, "text-allow-overlap": true, }
```

Full layer example:

```
const layer: mapboxgl.SymbolLayer = {
    id: 'layerID',
    type: 'symbol',
    source: {
        type: 'geojson',
        data: featureCollection,
    },
    layout: {
        "icon-image": "iconName",
        'symbol-sort-key': 1,
        'text-field': ['get', '<field in featureCollection you want to use>'],
        'text-font': ['Open Sans Regular'],
        'text-size': 10,
        'text-offset': [0, -1],
        'text-anchor': 'bottom',
        'icon-allow-overlap': true,
        "text-allow-overlap": true,
    },
    paint: {
        'text-color': '#000000',
        'text-halo-color': '#ffffff',
        'text-halo-width': 2,
    }
};

map.addLayer(layer)
```